# Error when running .apk jar file in allatori obfuscator

Tags: java, android, obfuscation

I am trying to run a classes.dex2jar.jar file (from an android .apk) in Allatori Java Obfuscator. However when ever I try to run Allatori Obfuscator on this .jar the process errors out with the following errors:

```
[WARNING] Class 'android.os.Binder' cannot be found.
[WARNING] Class 'android.os.IInterface' cannot be found.

com.allatori.iIIIiIIiII.THIS_IS_DEMO_VERSION_NOT_FOR_COMMERCIAL_USE(cz:462)
at com.allatori.iIIIiIIiII.IIIIiIiiII(cz:101)
at com.allatori.Obfuscate.THIS_IS_DEMO_VERSION_NOT_FOR_COMMERCIAL_USE(tq:894)
at com.allatori.Obfuscate.iIIiiIIIII(tq:835)
at com.allatori.Obfuscate.main(tq:109)
```